# nservicebus send command object with list type property using msmq transport

Tags: c#, nservicebus, msmq, distributed-system, generic-list

I have 2 nservicebus endpoints and the one endpoint is trying to send a command (class) object which contains 3 properties i.e. bool, List and class. Here is the complete command class below

```
public class StartProcess : ICommand
{
    public bool CanStartProcess { get; set; }
    public List<ProcessFailed> ProcessFailures { get; set; } = new List<ProcessFailed>();
    public ProcessFailed ProcessFailed { get; set; }
}
```

below is how I populate the object and I have confirmed that all properties contain valid values. I just simplied the code snipped a bit

```
var startProcess = new StartProcess()
{
    CanStartProcess = true,
    ProcessFailures = file.Body.ValidationReports,
    ProcessFailed = file.Body.ValidationReport
};
```

Lastly I start the endpoint and try to **send** the object . . . which is where my issue come

```
ClaimsProcessorEndpoint.Start();
ClaimsProcessorEndpoint.EndpointInstance.Send(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClaimsManager.Endpoint"], startProcess ).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Note: when I remove the list property then everything works fine. I am getting below exception:

```
exception.Message => The given key was not present in the dictionary.

exception.StackTrace
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
   at NServiceBus.XmlSerialization.Write(XElement elem, Type t, Object obj)
   at NServiceBus.XmlSerialization.WriteObject(XElement elem, String name, Type type, Object value, Boolean useNS)
   at NServiceBus.XmlSerialization.WriteEntry(XElement elem, String name, Type type, Object value)
   at NServiceBus.XmlSerialization.Write(XElement elem, Type t, Object obj)
   at NServiceBus.XmlSerialization.WriteObject(XElement elem, String name, Type type, Object value, Boolean useNS)
   at NServiceBus.XmlSerialization.WriteEntry(XElement elem, String name, Type type, Object value)
   at NServiceBus.XmlSerialization.Write(XElement elem, Type t, Object obj)
   at NServiceBus.XmlSerialization.WriteObject(XElement elem, String name, Type type, Object value, Boolean useNS)
   at NServiceBus.XmlSerialization.Serialize()
   at NServiceBus.XmlMessageSerializer.Serialize(Object message, Stream stream)
   at NServiceBus.SerializeMessageConnector.Serialize(IOutgoingLogicalMessageContext context)
   at NServiceBus.SerializeMessageConnector.<Invoke>d__1.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NServiceBus.UnicastSendRouterConnector.<Invoke>d__1.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
```

Looking at NServicebus tutorial (image), this should not be a problem. And on both endpoints I am using XmlSerializer [image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you are not providing all types part of your message.

Probably something happens during serialization because you are assigning `file.Body.ValidationReports` to `startProcess.ProcessFailures` which trips the serializer.

Are the types in `file.Body.ValidationReports` of type `ProcessFailed` or maybe inherited from it and extending that class? If so, try to map these results to new `ProcessFailed` objects.

Meaning,

```cs
var startProcess = new StartProcess()
{
    CanStartProcess = true,
    ProcessFailures = file.Body.ValidationReports.Select(x=>new ProcessFailed{A=x.A, B=x.B}).ToList(),
    ProcessFailed = file.Body.ValidationReport
};
```

Comment: you're right I should have given more information, but the **ProcessFailed** class has 2 public methods i.e.

Comment: @Tumelo Could you provide a full types so that we could create a reproduction?

Comment: I was not finished typing my initial comment and pressed the enter key expecting to get a new line, but alas it posted the comment. Here's my full comment

you're right I should have given more information, but the **ProcessFailed** class has 2 public methods i.e.

`public bool Validate()`
`public bool Parse()`

this is what was causing the issue and adding [XmlIgnore] tag does not work on methods. I moved the methods out and left the class with only properties

Comment: @Tumelo So removing the methods resolved this issue? May I suggest that you add this as an anwser to this question?

Comment: What version of NServiceBus is this? I've tried to reproduce this with methods but it just works: https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/pull/5639 please provide any info if you can reproduce it.

Comment: this is version 7.0.1 using XmlSerializer with Msmq persistence